# Use Dynamic Query in a Procedure and call that procedure in a select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to execute a dynamic query in SQL Server and show the result in a select query.

Since, we cannot use dynamic queries in functions, we have written a stored procedure to return the dynamic query value.

But how can i call my stored procedure in a select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally would use the key word `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` to call a stored procedure.

yet there is a way of selecting data from a stored procedure using `OPENQUERY`.

```
SELECT  * FROM 
OPENQUERY(SERVERNAME, 'EXECUTE Proc_Name @parameters')
```